# Get main function value into kendo grid read function

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I am creating kendo grid wrapper JavaScript function. I am using sever side paging and filtering.

My Code:

```
function kendoGridCustom(){
    this.self = this;
    this.serviceBaseURL = "http://localhost:57890/";
    this.serviceReadURL = 'Book/Index';

    this.LoadDataSource = function() {
         this.dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    type: "json",
                    transport: {
                        read: function (options) {

                            $.ajax({
                                url: this.serviceBaseURL + this.serviceReadURL,
                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: JSON.stringify(options),
                                success: function (result) {
                                     options.success(result);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: "Data",
                        total: 'Total',
                        errors: 'Errors',
                        model: {
                            fields: [{  id : { type: "number" }},
                    {  name : { type: "string" }}]
                        }
                    }
        ,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverPaging: true,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    serverSorting: true,
                    pageable: {
                        pageSizes: [10, 20, 50],
                        numeric: false
                    }
                });

    }

}
```

Right now ,I am trying to call `LoadDataSource` function to load the datasource. 
I am using a server base URL and read URL to get filter row which I have created.

url: this.serviceBaseURL + this.serviceReadURL,

I can not able to access this value (current class value)

Please help me solve this.

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: Improve readability

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why are you trying to do with `this` keyword. What is `this` in your function `kendoGridCustom()`?

Is that function inside the kendo `observable` object? Or is it in browsers  `window` object?

Try something like this:

```
function kendoGridCustom() {
    var serviceBaseURL = "http://localhost:57890/";
    var serviceReadURL = 'Book/Index';

    $.ajax({
       url: serviceBaseURL + serviceReadURL;
    });
}
```

Comment: var grid = new  kendoGridCustom();